# OpenCart: Add home to menu and remove from header

Tags: opencart

1. I was wondering what is the best way to remove `Home` from the header and place `Home` in the menu?
2. Should it be done only in the custom theme, default theme, or both?

I have in the past done:

Edit:

```
catalog/view/theme/mytheme/template/common/header.tpl
```

located:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
```

and added:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $text_home; ?></a></li>
```

I am unsure though if it is better to modify the default theme instead of the custom theme. Any advise would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only needs to be done in your custom theme. You don't need to do this in the default theme unless your theme uses the default template for the header (and in that case you really should still duplicate the header file from default to your theme and edit that)

### EDIT

Open `/catalog/view/theme/your-theme-name/template/common/header.php` to find the text. Will usually look something like

```
<a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $text_home; ?></a>
```

Remove that and save the file

Comment: thanks.  I've read much debate about this topic on the OpenCart forum.

Comment: Do you mind adding how to remove `Home` from the header so I can except your answer?

Comment: thanks, I would assume no issues with removing it and adding in the menu?

Comment: None at all, it's all purely aesthetic